# CSS Bootstrap Modal заменить затемнение на засветление

Tags: css, bootstrap

Как сделать так, чтобы при использовании стандартного всплывающего bootstrap модального окна фон страницы не затемнялся, а наоборот становился чуть светлее или менялся каким-либо образом параметр прозрачности. Я поискал стандартные параметры в документации, но не нашел такой возможности. https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/modal/? Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В css задвайте стили фону:

```css
@import "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css";

.modal-backdrop {
  background: #fff;
}

.modal-backdrop.show {
  opacity: .8;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" ></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
  <!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: А `!important` точно нужен?

Comment: @Qwertiy, это тут на stack почему-то style не перебивает бутстраповские стили, а так не нужен, у меня и без него перебивает нормально

Comment: А, ясно. Это потому что у тебя тут получается твой стиль в head, а бутстраповский в body. Поправил :)

Comment: @Qwertiy, спасибо